# Part of form not showing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 4 app where I'm following basically [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised):

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @store, do |f| %>

   <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
      <%= render "product_fields",  f: builder %>
   <% end %>
   <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Product", f, :products  %>
<% end %>
```

_product_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :the_product_type, %w[Shelves, Tools, Wires]%>
<div>
   <%= f.fields_for :product_fields do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.text_area :name_of_product_field %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

My JS looks like:

```
$('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(e) {
    var regexp, time;
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));

    return e.preventDefault();
 });
```

My issue is that when I click the Add Product button, I can only see a select. I can't see the name_of_product_field textarea. But I can't figure out why I can see the select if I can't see the textarea?

Comment: is it an `html` issue ?

Comment: Does each product has many `product_fields`? Also, you should look into `cocoon` gem, it should make your life easier - not too easy though as you want nested associations here. (Don't know if it is recommended in the screencast as it is premium, but according to comments  it is not)

Comment: @BroiSatse, Yes, each product has_many product_fields. I looked into cocoon, but I really want to try this without using a gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product_fields` is a nested attribute which you have not `build` anywhere in your code which is why you are not seeing it.

Assuming that *a product has_many product_fields*, you can resolve this issue in two ways, choose one that suits you:

**1. Build it at Controller level**

Build the `product_fields` in the `Controller#action` which is rendering the problematic view:

```
def action_name
  @store = Store.new
  product = @store.products.build
  product.product_fields.build
end
```

**2.Build it at View level**

Update the `fields_for` in `_product_fields.html.erb` as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_fields, f.object.product_fields.build do |builder| %>
```